# From template variable How to retrieve uploaded file value in ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms

From template variable want to get upload file.

```
<input type="file" (change)="uploadPhoto()" #fileInput>
```

property

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput:ElementRef;
```

In ts how I am supposed to get upload file

```
upload (){
    var nativeElement:HTMLInputElement= this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    console.log("native", nativeElement.files[0]);//**TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.**
}
```

Comment: You need to start by naming your function the same in both places.

Comment: @ Chris Sharp both places have same template variable name. Check my above syntax,problem happen in here nativeElement.files[0] not in here nativeElement!.files[0].